# English medical records in a Spanish-speaking country?

Tags: health, languages, language-barrier

I'm travelling to Uruguay - the main language is Spanish.

I'm planning on taking a physical copy of my medical records with me, in the event of an emergency. (These records can be obtained through my insurance, I'm sure, or I could have them faxed internationally, but I figure it's better to be safe than sorry!)

These records are in English. Questions:

1. Will I run into any problems with English medical records in a Spanish-speaking country?
2. Are there any ways to mitigate this - medical records translation services that will provide a physical copy, or anything?

(NOTE: My travel insurance has a hotline for language situations, but translating medical records over the phone doesn't seem advisable.)

Comment: I thought all medical records are in Latin worldwide?

Comment: @ŁukaszLech I never thought of that - they might be. I don't really know anything about the medical field, though. This isn't just a Spanish question, but more of a general question - should records be translated to your destination language.

Answer (score 5):

You'll find that Uruguay is quite modern so you'll have a very high chance of finding an English speaker at most hospitals. Still, it's great that you want to be prepared so I'm sure having a certified translation of your papers won't hurt either. I'm pretty sure you'll be fine with just your English papers though.

Comment: I'm Uruguayan and I can vouch for everything @Michael states here :) 

Most educated people have a basic notion of english here. However, I wouldn't expect much technical knowledge in English from doctors. Having your records translated (maybe not even professionally) would be of great help.